# Editing Conky configuration variables from Lua

Tags: conky, lua

I've been messing around with Conky for a while now and I recently started dabbling in Lua scripting. One of the things that used to bug me about a "flat" `conkyrc` approach (as opposed to a combined `conkyrc` and `lua` script) was that you had to set the position for everything using trial and error.

Using `lua` and `cairo` I was hoping to avoid that: I get the screen resolution from `xdpyinfo` and make all my dimensions relative to the screen resolution. The problem with this approach is that I still need to adjust the Conky window position from within the `conkyrc` file and (as far as I know) it can't be done programmatically. So my question is, can I use the results from my `lua` script to set Conky configuration variables like `gap_x` and `gap_y`? Or is there maybe another way to set these variables programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the solution I had in mind, but a solution nonetheless:
the [Conky Lua API](http://conky.sourceforge.net/lua.html) describes a `conky_config` function that returns "[a] string containing the path of the current Conky configuration file."

So my solution would be to open this file and edit it in place from within my `lua` script.